# Create historical data in Microsoftlist

Tags: microsoft-lists

I have created a microsoftlist that shows risk management. Risk level shows probablity (P) times consequence (C). So riskvalue in tertiary 1 is 12. When we are in tertiary 2 the riskvalue will maybe change. So I want to show development. For example if T1 changes from T1 to T2 I want to dsplay risk value from T1 in column "Last value of risklevel". Column "Last value of risklevel" will always show the value from last tertiary. So my question is it easy way to solve this in microsoftlits? I am not expert in

[image]